# Spacy and sputnik issue on Python3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow, spacy

I am currently using space(0.101.0), tensorflox (1.0.0) and sputnik (0.9.3). I do have this issue happening :

```
  super(Pool, self).__init__(app_name, app_version, path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sebastien/xxx/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/Users/sebastien/xxx/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 51, in load
    for package in self.packages():
  File "/Users/sebastien/xxx/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package_list.py", line 47, in packages
    yield self.__class__.package_class(path=os.path.join(self.path, path))
  File "/Users/sebastien/xxx/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/package.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package'])
KeyError: 'package'
```

I have tried to combine different version but my make stuff is no more working.  I have issues to build the overall system.

Based on what I gave as version used, This issue also happened when I am running the "python3 -m spacy.en.download"

Any idea?